# Return live search results in order of keystrokes - Django and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django

I am trying to build a search bar that allows user to search database for the names of stored venues. I want it to be a live search that returns results as the user types. Similar to google.

I have gotten the feature almost complete, it dynamically returns venues as the user types and returns venues that contain the letters being typed.

Problem:
I can't figure out how to return venues that contain letters IN ORDER of typing. [Example from google.](https://ibb.co/Tk6WZWv) [How mine shows up.](https://ibb.co/B3JGncg)

Here is my JS Function:

```
const search = function() {
  let searchTerm = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/electra/search/',
    data: {
      'search_term': searchTerm
    },
    success: function(data) {
      data.forEach(([cafeName]) => {
        var cafeName = cafeName;
        var searchList = $(
          `<div>
                  <ul class="list-item border-top" data-idtext="${cafeName}" id="${cafeName}">${cafeName}</ul>
              </div>`
        );
        searchList.appendTo('#search-results');
      });

      $("ul").click(function(event) {
        var selectedVenue = event.target.id;
        $("#search-results").empty()
        getVenueDetails(selectedVenue)
      });
    }
  });
};
```

And here is the views.py function:

```
def search(request):
    template_name = 'testingland/write_image.html'
    search_term = request.GET.get('search_term', None)
    print(search_term)
    qs = mapCafes.objects.filter(cafe_name__icontains = search_term)[0:5]
    return JsonResponse([
            [cafe.cafe_name]
            for cafe in qs
    ], safe=False)
```

Comment: The difference is your code returns results that contain (%term%) the search term, google returns this that begin (term%) with it.

Comment: Sorry could  you clarify what you mean?

Comment: You are returning results where the search term can be anywhere. So if someone is typing ‘bo’ you are getting ‘booth’ as well as ‘robot’ or ‘hobo’. Change your search syntax so it only returns results that begins with ‘bo’ only.